# Is this content of a rebased commit different to that of the original commit?

Tags: git-commit, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

I am trying to understand why repetitive conflicts occur during rebasing. I begin with the concept that if a conflict is resolved and thus results in *new* commits being created, there should be no more conflicts from there on.

In the [Object Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#_object_storage) section of the git documentation it explains that a commit object contains a header, the previous content of the file and the new content of the file, or *before* and *after* states.

If I `git rebase` and resolve a conflict during the rebase, does the new commit contain a different "before" state than the original commit?

I surmise that if the *new* commit contains the exact same *before* and *after* state content the commit and all it's future duplicates (created from further rebasing) will continue to cause conflicts. It stands to reason that `git rerere` would use that content as a fingerprint to match future conflicts with past conflicts and be able to auto-resolve them.

If, however, the *new* commits do not contain updated content in the *before* state there are two questions:

1. Why does future rebasing cause repetitive conflicts, and
2. How does git know what to put in the *new before* state?